# How do check for a specific character at the end of each line in a text file

Tags: python

I've written a script that appends a given character onto every line of a text file (I'm adding `','` to the end of IP addresses, one per row)

I want to prevent accidentally running the script multiple times and adding multiple of the same characters to the end of the script. i.e. adding one `,` is what I want, accidentally adding ten `,`'s is annoying and I'll need to undo what I've done.

I'm trying to update the code to identify if the last character in a line is the same as the character that's trying to be added and if it is, not to add it.

This code adds `char` to the end of each line.

```
file = 'test.txt' # file to append text to, keep the '' 
char = ','

newf=""
with open(file,'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        newf+=line.strip()+ char + '\n'
    f.close()

with open(file,'w') as f:
    f.write(newf)

f = open("test.txt", "r")
check = ","
```

And I've written this code to check what the last character per line is, it returns a `','` successfully for each line. **What I can't figure out is how to combine if `char` and `check` are the same value, not to append anything.**

```
f = open("test.txt", "r")
check = ","

for line in f:
    l = line.strip()
    if l[-1:].isascii():
        check = l[-1:]
    else:
        check = 0
    print(check)

f.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the `endswith()` function to check if it already ends with `,`.

```
check = ","
newf = ""

with open(file) as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        if not line.endswith(check):
            line += check
        newf += line + "\n"
```

Comment: `Statements must be separated by newlines or semicolons` on line 5

Comment: Sorry, typo at the end of that line

Comment: removed the : and it seems to work

Comment: Is there anything I should bear in mine with writing the output? i.e. does it matter to append or re-write?

Comment: You should rewrite, otherwise you'll combine the old contents with the new contents.

Comment: Added; with open(file, 'w') as f:f.write(newf) to the end, is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes, that's already in the original code. I was just showing how to fix the loop that reads.